# Python 3 - Importing System and Relative Imports concept

Tags: python, python-import

I am fairly new to Python, specifically Python3; learning the ropes here.

**Problem Summary**:
Can be summarized in not fully understanding how the import system works in Python and what exactly is relative import, though I'll mention what I actually understand and please correct me if there are any misconceptions here.

**My Understanding**:
Python behaves differently whether a python file "file.py" is ran from the REPL using `python file.py` vs importing this file using `import file.py`, this behavior differs in the value assignment of  `__name__` variable; in the first case its given the value `'__main__'` and in the second case its given the value `__file__` which is usually the fully qualified path followed to import this file. Upon importing a module; python doesn't save the hierarchy it has followed to fetch it, hence if there are modules needed to be imported within the same level of the previously imported module, then a fully qualified name is still needed.

---

**Context:**

Consider the following directory

```
Main:
|______ main.py
|
|______ PackageOne:
|
|______ ______ __init__.py
|
|______ ______ ModuleOne.py
|
|______ ______ PackageTwo:
|
|______ ______ ______ __init__.py
|
|______ ______ ______ ModuleTwo.py
```

structure details:

- `main.py` => program entry ("first file to be ran via IDE").
- `PackageOne` => a package folder containing an `__init__.py` initializer
  and a `ModuleOne.py` module.

  - `__init__.py` => the initializing python file of `PackageOne` which imports `ModuleOne.py` module
    and `PackageTwo`
  - ModuleOne.py a module python file that contains a function named `FuncOne()`
- `PackageTwo` => a package folder containing an `__init__.py` initializer
  and a `ModuleTwo.py` module.

  - `__init__.py` => the initializing python file of `PackageTwo` which imports `ModuleTwo.py` module
  - `ModuleTwo.py` a module python file that contains a function named `FuncTwo()`
    Files content:
    **main.py**:

  import PackageOne
  **PackageOne / __init__**:

  print(f"From ParentPackage, Name:{**name**}")
  import PackageTwo, ModuleOne

**PackageOne / ModuleOne**:

```
def FuncOne():
    print(__name__)
```

**PackageTwo/ __init__**:

```
print(f"From ParentPackage, Name:{__name__}")
import ModuleTwo
```

**PackageTwo/ ModuleTwo**:

```
def FuncTwo():
    print(__name__)
```

---

**Detailed Problem:**

- **A):** An output of

> No Module Named 'PackageTwo'

pops up. and upon removing PackageTwo from import, the same occurs for ModuleOne.

- **B):** Upon refactoring the code of files like so:

  **PackageOne / __init__**:

  ```
   print(f"From ParentPackage, Name:{__name__}")
   from PackageOne import PackageTwo, ModuleOne
  ```

  **PackageTwo/ __init__**:

  ```
   print(f"From ParentPackage, Name:{__name__}")
   from PackageOne.PackageTwo import ModuleTwo
  ```

Running main.py causes no problems whatsoever and prints out "From ParentPackage, Name:PackageOne" and "From ChildPackage, Name:PackageOne.PackageTwo", but trying to execute any of the `__init__.py` files directly outputs an error of

> No Module Named:'PackageOne'

which seems counter-intuitive to the concept of modularity in the sense of dividing the code into small parts for reusability / readability, but not actually being able to run the code from the same scope its written in, or the flexibility of importing it from a different scope. Though I instantly thought maybe relative import would probably help solve this case? but it seems that my understanding of relative import is not concrete, so a brush up on this topic would really help.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of bold, please use single backticks to mark inline bits of code.  (I converted a few.  When doing so, underscores do not need escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to some what solve this issue, but this wouldn't be considered a decent approach as it increases coupling between dependancies.

```
if __name__ != "__main__":
    import importlib
    my_module = importlib.import_module(f'{__name__}.ModuleOne')
else:
    import ModuleOne
```

`importlib.import_module(f'{__name__}.ModuleOne')` is a function that imports Modules and by providing the path / caller of the import keyword `__name__`, I'am able to import `ModuleOne` from any scope.

this would be placed within the `PackageOne \ __init__.py` , by doing so I can easily run the `__init__.py` file directly or by importing it, but by explicitly typing a string representation of `ModuleOne` within the importing function it makes it impossible to auto-refactor upon changing the dependancies name. This answer is to some what guide myself in the direction of how things work and maybe find a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've finally figured it out, there were a couple of missing information, please correct me if I am wrong.

1. from `__a__` import `__b__` can be in two contexts:

   - Script File: `__a__` here can only be the name of a module or a sub directory, while `__b__` can be an attribute of the module to be inserted. which begs the question, how to import modules from different directories if the python file is being ran as a script? we start adding the directory to the list of directories that python searches within using `sys.path.append("directory path needed")`, importing `sys` of course prior to that.
   - Module: module meaning that this python file is going to be imported into another module or directly into the script file that is being ran, hence the `__a__` part can either be a module name from a directory that exists in the `sys.path` like the examples above, or a directory; for example `from child import module`. **Note**: It's important to know that when using Absolute paths its important to start the directory path from the root package up to the required package or module. Instead relative paths can be used.
   - Conclusion: `__name__` when is evaluated to `"__main__"` due to running the python file as a script, its unable to traverse to other paths using the `from` keyword.
2. `__init__.py` files aren't meant to be ran as scripts hence they sometimes include importing modules or other packages using the `from directory` keyboard.
3. Correlation of the above two points, the relative import such `from . import package` is only valid for modules and `__init__.py` of packages which is a module itself and not scripts.
4. Sibling packages do not require changing directories to access each other.

---

**Summary**:

When working on a module you can use `from directory` and `from . (relative paths)`, but when working on a script if there is a specific module needed from a different directory then add it to the path using `sys.path.append("directory")`, finally `__init__.py` of packages are modules, not scripts. (if needed to work as a script/module then an if condition `if __name__ != __main__: relative import` or another work around is required).